# Compilation error when using GetComputerObjectNameW win API

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am getting compilation error with below code on visual studio. Kindly help me to understand problem.
If you are not having visual studio you can try to compile code at following link https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <secext.h>


int main()
{
        EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT enf = NameFullyQualifiedDN;
        LPWSTR pwszComputerName;
        DWORD dwLen;
        
        dwLen = 0;
        GetComputerObjectNameW(enf, NULL, &dwLen);
    
        pwszComputerName = new WCHAR[dwLen + 1];
        if(NULL == pwszComputerName)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(!GetComputerObjectNameW(NameSamCompatible, pwszComputerName, &dwLen))
        {
            delete pwszComputerName;
            return 0;
        }

        sbstrTrustee = pwszComputerName;
        wprintf(L"GetComputerObjectName: %s\n", pwszComputerName);
        delete pwszComputerName;
        return 0
}
```

Errors are as below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(117): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetUserNameExA'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(121): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(126): error C2086: 'BOOLEAN SEC_ENTRY': redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(117): note: see declaration of 'SEC_ENTRY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(126): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetUserNameExW'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(130): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(140): error C2086: 'BOOLEAN SEC_ENTRY': redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(117): note: see declaration of 'SEC_ENTRY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(140): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetComputerObjectNameA'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(144): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(147): error C2086: 'BOOLEAN SEC_ENTRY': redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(117): note: see declaration of 'SEC_ENTRY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(147): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetComputerObjectNameW'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(151): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(161): error C2086: 'BOOLEAN SEC_ENTRY': redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(117): note: see declaration of 'SEC_ENTRY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(161): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'TranslateNameA'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(167): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(170): error C2086: 'BOOLEAN SEC_ENTRY': redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(117): note: see declaration of 'SEC_ENTRY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(170): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'TranslateNameW'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared\secext.h(176): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
source_file.cpp(28): error C2065: 'sbstrTrustee': undeclared identifier
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in this code:

1. You should include `security.h` instead of `secext.h` (see [including secExt.h causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279276/including-secext-h-causes-errors)).
2. You must define one of `SECURITY_WIN32`, `SECURITY_KERNEL`, or `SECURITY_MAC` (see [SSPI header file - fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561475/sspi-header-file-fatal-error)).
3. `sbstrTrustee` variable is not declared.
4. there is no `;` after `return 0` statement.

Assuming your application is user-mode windows the code could be as follows:

```
#define SECURITY_WIN32 
#include <iostream>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <security.h>

int main()
{
  EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT enf = NameFullyQualifiedDN;
  LPWSTR pwszComputerName;
  DWORD dwLen;

  dwLen = 0;
  GetComputerObjectNameW(enf, NULL, &dwLen);

  pwszComputerName = new WCHAR[dwLen + 1];
  if (NULL == pwszComputerName)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if (!GetComputerObjectNameW(NameSamCompatible, pwszComputerName, &dwLen))
  {
    delete pwszComputerName;
    return 0;
  }

  //sbstrTrustee = pwszComputerName;
  wprintf(L"GetComputerObjectName: %s\n", pwszComputerName);
  delete pwszComputerName;
  return 0;
}
```

You also have to link `Secur32.lib`.

Comment: Hi Nevilad, 
Thanks for quick response but I am not getting expected result. This program is returning before wprintf.

Comment: Your question is about compilation errors. You did not mention what results you expect.

Comment: What does GetComputerObjectNameW return? Call GetLastError after failing GetComputerObjectNameW calls to get the reason of the failure.